# How do Exposé and Spaces work in OS X?

Tags: macos, osx-spaces, expose

How do Exposé and Spaces work in OS X?

I am looking for details like

- When do these applications start?
- What framework do they use to create these effects?
- Any other details might help me understand these application better?

Comment: Why? What do you want to do? Any specific programming task?

Comment: I am just curious how they work and who manages their working.

Comment: They are also related to the Dock process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac OS X uses the Quartz Compositor to render desktop effects. Since Mac OS X 10.2, desktop effects were rendered with hardware acceleration, easing load on the CPU.

To learn more about Quartz Compositor, see here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_Compositor